# Visualizations work in Windows Media Player, but not Windows Media Center?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, windows-media-center, visualization

Maybe its been fixed in the RTM, but on my HTPC I'm running Windows 7 RC. I've installed some visualizations, and they work fine in Windows Media Player, but they're not showing up as options in Windows Media Center.

Things I've done so far:

- I've gone into the settings (inside WMC) to make sure they were checked as available (they're no there to check...)
- I've gone in the advanced settings in WMP to make sure there wasn't an error buried somewhere.
- I've rebooted a couple of times
- I've checked the drive to make sure the *.dll was in the right folder (it is as far as I can tell)
- I am as up-to-date on Windows Updates as I can get
- I've got the most current drivers for my video card

Any ideas on how to fix this?

---

**Update:**

I should have mentioned that I'm using Windows 7 *x64*.

Comment: Great... further Google searches show my question as the top result. :;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the visualizations were designed for a 32-bit media player (which is the default edition of WMP) - they do not work in the 64-bit WMP or WMC - and it seems the only version of Media Center that ships with 7 x64 is 64-bit.

That is why they were working in WMP and not WMC.

I'm stuck until more people start shipping 64 bit visualizations...

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed any fancy visualizations products?

If yes, uninstalling them might improve the situation, as some products break visualizations for WMC even if they do still work for WMP.

Comment: If your talking about visualizations <i>packs</i>, just ones provided and signed by Microsoft...